# Cannot generate linphone++ headers for windows-sdk

Tags: linphone-sdk

I would like to build liblinphone for C++ on Windows and modify it for my own testing purposes. Has anyone successfully built linphone-sdk or linphone-desktop in a way that generates linphone++? If so, could you please provide the necessary cmake commands?

Thanks for your help.